# How to show long list of web service results to user?

Tags: java, database, web-services, jakarta-ee

I need to retrieve long list of results from different web services and after sorting them show to user. So far I have received all the results and put them in a class called result class.

I am not sure what would be an efficient way to handle them. Should I put them in Database then show them to user or keep them in memory (which I suppose is not a good idea!) or if there is any other alternative method ?

```
 User makes a search request
 Web service client requests to receive results from 
           first webservice put results into result class
           second webservice put results into result class
           third webservice put results into result class
           .....
 Sort the results based on their name
 Show the results to user.
```

result class

```
 public class Result { 
     private long id; 
     private String name;
     private String source;
     private float code;
     .....
 }
```

Scenario is like, each user sends a request to see a list of students. 
lets say a user wants to  see a list of students who are more than 18 years old, the system sends the request to all web services to get their list of students over 18 once all info are received the system puts all the info together sort them and show them to user. Users are able to search based on age, first name etc of each student, data need to be in real time as students info is changing all the time on all servers.

Comment: why did you vote up for closing the question? let me know your reason rather than doing it straightaway!!!

Comment: This question does not fit for what Stack Overflow is designed for. You may have better results on another Stack Exchange site, perhaps User Experience or Code Review. That is another part of the problem: it is unclear whether you want to improve your user experience or your performance, and otherwise what exactly you want help with. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems with specific solutions, and this is not one of them.

Comment: @Saposhiente I see, I thought it is clear as I asked what should I do with the data that I receive should I keep them in memory or save in DB and retrieve from there. As I am not sure which approach is the best I have not coded it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The question you need to ask yourself is:

> For how long after the data is retrieved is the data relevant/would I need it?

- If the data is relevant for hours/days/weeks/... then the database is
  where you should put it.
- If the data is relevant for a few minutes then store it in the users session (memory).
- *If when a request is made, you fetch the data (from the different web services), do whatever processing on that data and return the output in the response, you generally wouldn't keep the data in memory.*
  Edit:
  If the data should be returned "real-time" (no caching), the data should not live in memory after the response.

---

Tip:
If you are going to be caching the data in memory, look at using something like http://ehcache.org/ or http://www.terracotta.org/.
If you decide to keep it in a database, store the date and time when the data essentially expires, then have something (your app, crontab or whatever you decide to use) clear out the data where the expiry time is in the past.

Comment: Actually data is going to be available in real time, so users make requests and need to receive the most updated results. Therefore I need to make the request to all web services per users' requests.

Comment: All parts of your answer are clear except the last part, which is "you generally would not keep the data in memory." I need to show the results to each user based on their requests so each request and result would be different with the other ones.

Comment: I've edited the 3rd point.  What I meant was, the data should be cleared out of memory when the response is sent...

Comment: thanks so whats your suggestion? first user make the request, I send the requests to all web services then show the result to user and clear up the memory, while serving second user in real time? Imagine 1000 users are using the system synonymously , then the memory should be really big to support them all right?

Comment: The data will only be in memory between the request and the response.  one other point I neglected to ask, is the data unique per user, is it  the same across the board (or something between the 2)?

Comment: Scenario is like, each user sends a request to see a list of students lets say more than 18 years old, the system sends the request to all web services to get their list of students over 18 once all info are received the system puts all the info together sort them and show them to user. Users are able to search based on age, first name etc of each student, data need to be in real time as students info is changing all the time on all servers.

Comment: Do you have skype, Stackoverflow isn't working for this.  I'm happy to help you further...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47082/discussion-between-neila-and-j888)